# вылезает ошибка "vector subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, vector, динамические-массивы

Вот код:
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
ifstream inf("Text.txt");

void getElements(double **ptrarray, int n) {
int choice;
do {
    cout << "Введите 1, если хотите получить элементы матрицы из файла и 2, если элементы матрицы 
получаем по формуле" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
} while (choice != 1 && choice != 2);
if (choice == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            inf >> ptrarray[i][j];
}
else if (choice == 2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i == 0)
                i++;
            if (j == 0)
                j++;
            ptrarray[i][j] = (2.2 + j * sqrt(8.4 * i + 1)) / (pow(10, log(i * j)) + 5);
        }
}
}

void fillVector(double** ptrarray, int n, vector<double> vect) {
vector<double> array; // вспомогательный массив, в котором хранятся суммы i-тых строк
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        array[i] += ptrarray[i][j];
    
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    vect[i] = log(array[i]);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << vect[i] << " ";
cout << "\n";
}

void sortArray(double** ptrarray, int n) {
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sort(ptrarray[i], ptrarray[i] + n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        cout << ptrarray[i][j] << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
}

double calculate_y(vector<double> vect, int n) {
double y = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= n - 1; i++)
    y += (vect[i - 1] / vect[i] + vect[i] / vect[i + 1]);
return y;
}

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
cout << "Введите размер матрицы" << endl;
int n;
cin >> n;
double** ptrarray = new double* [n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    ptrarray[i] = new double[n];
vector<double> vect;
getElements(ptrarray, n);
fillVector(ptrarray, n, vect);
sortArray(ptrarray, n);
cout << "y = " << calculate_y(vect, n);
}
```

`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить

Comment: не вылезать за пределы вектора

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка доступа к элементам массива, строки, вектора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1341757/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)