# Ошибка доступа к элементам массива, строки, вектора

Tags: c++, c++-faq

При использовании в программе массива, строки или вектора в процессе выполнения возникают ошибки вида:

- array subscript out of range
- string subscript out of range
- vector subscript out of range
- Segmentation fault (core dumped)
- Access violation reading location
- Access violation writing location
- нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу ...
- нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подобные ошибки означают, что во время работы программы была предпринята попытка обращения к памяти, не подготовленной должным образом для этого. Программа с такими ошибками содержит [неопределённое поведение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/900292/176217). Самыми говорящими из рассмотренных в вопросе ошибок являются те, где сказано "subscript out of range". Дословно это переводится как "Индексация вне диапазона". Понятность их обеспечивается в первую очередь тем, что программа собрана в отладочном (Debug) режиме и соответствующий код индексации `operator[]` того или иного контейнера (`std::array`, `std::string`, `std::vector`) непосредственно содержит проверку значения индекса, передаваемого в оператор индексации. Например, так выглядит код в msvc 2019 для `std::array`:

```
    _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR17 reference operator[](_In_range_(0, _Size - 1) size_type _Pos) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
#if _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0
        _STL_VERIFY(_Pos < _Size, "array subscript out of range");
#endif // _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

        return _Elems[_Pos];
    }
```

Другие сообщения не так очевидны, потому что возникают при работе приложений, собранных без отладочной информации и/или оптимизированных так, что подробное отладочное сообщение не содержится/не связано с выполняемый кодом, но причины их возникновения часто те же самые.

Решение проблемы прямо вытекает из текста отладочных сообщений - индекс, по которому идёт обращение к элементу контейнера, должен быть в допустимом диапазоне. Т.е. если контейнер имеет размер `N`, допустимыми индексами будут являться `0...N-1`. Исключением из этого правила является `std::string`, где допускается так же использовать индекс `N`, но с оговоркой, что писать туда можно только нулевой символ `\0`, и он же вернётся при чтении.

Довольно часто проблема выхода за допустимые границы диапазона случается в циклах, когда условие завершение содержит нестрогое сравнение индекса с размером контейнера: т.е. `i <= size` вместо `i < size`. В подобных случаях итерации по элементам, следует по возможности пользоваться диапазонной версией цикла `for`, которая не допускает выхода за пределы контейнера, если размер контейнера остаётся постоянным в процессе итерирования.

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
for(int i = 0; i <= v.size(); ++i) // ошибка. <= вместо <
   v[i] = 42;                      // проблема на последней итерации

for(auto& e : v)                   // диапазонный for 
   e = 42;                         // e всегда принадлежит вектору
```

Иногда цикл кажется правильным, но вместо `v.size()` по незнанию указывают [`v.max_size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size), который говорит вообще о потенциально возможном размере контейнера для данной архитектуры, а не о текущем размере. Понятно, что в этом случае можно выйти далеко за пределы разрешённых величин.

При этом даже в циклах, где правильно заданы границы индексов можно использовать не тот элемент, т.к. конкретный индекс вычисляется как функция от индекса из цикла, например:

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
   v[f(i)] = ...   // f(i) может возвращать другой диапазон
   v[i - 1] = ...  // использование "предыдущего" индекса. Ошибка для i == 0.
}
```

Другой возможный случай - когда возникает путаница между ассоциативными контейнерами (где `operator[]` приводит к созданию/добавлению элемента в контейнер, если его ещё не было) и последовательными контейнерами. Например:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
m[0] = 42; // ok, добавляется элемент с ключом 0 и ему присваивается значение 42

std::vector<int> v;
v[0] = 42; // ошибка, вектор пустой, элемента с индексом 0 не существует
```

Добавить элемент в вектор можно либо при инициализации `std::vector<int> v = {42};`,  либо позднее, например, через `v.push_back(42)`.

Иногда ошибка может возникать, когда вместо `std::vector::resize` был вызван `std::vector::reserve`. Т.е. память выделена и доступ идёт только к элементам внутри выделенной памяти, но логически размер вектора не был изменён (элементы вектора фактически не проинициализированы). При Release сборке в этом случае может вовсе не возникнуть ошибки доступа (access violation), но такая программа не будет считаться валидной.

Чтобы обеспечить дополнительную проверку диапазона используемых индексов как в отладочном, так и в релизном режимах сборки вместо `operator[]` можно воспользоваться функцией `at()`, которая выбросит исключение `std::out_of_range` при использовании индекса вне разрешённого диапазона. В некоторых случаях сложного вычисления индекса это может быть оправдано, но внесёт дополнительный оверхед.

Comment: «`std::string`, где допускается так же использовать индекс `N`, но только на чтение». Ну, писать туда вроде как тоже можно, но только нулевой символ. См.: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) и [string.access / 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.access#2).

Comment: @wololo подкорректировал ответ.