# UE 4 attempted to access index 20 from array

Tags: unreal-engine-4, blueprint

Столкнулся с тем что при переводе цифровых значений в переменную Float перестал работать Boolean массив, и движок не может получить данные для корректной работы.[image: ошибка]

Как это работает: [image: линия работы 1]я использую Data table с определёнными значениями и параметрами в Float. Далее устанавливаю Длину массива и делаю ресайз.

Далее идёт другая часть нодов где я добавляю предмет из индекса, произвожу мат. операции и вывожу значение в бранч. После этого идёт сиквенс, который начинает получать деньги из предмета и следом идёт бранч который получаяет данны от переменной и из массива, которая и выдаёт ошибку. (он обведён белым) [image: элемент который содержит ошибку]

Я пробовал перевести абсолютно все расчёты в Float в надежде что это поможет не создавать конфликты, но массив так и не заработал.

Подскажите как исправить его, так как если вернуть всё в Int64 то он работает. Или же посоветуйте документацию по работе с массивами.

P.s. не стесняйтесь просить больше контекста для понимания работы нодов

Comment: Судя по первому скрину с текстом ошибки, у вас обычный выход за пределы массива. Плюсами, правда, в вопросе не особо пахнет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ как это можно исправить? Можете что-то посоветовать
И почему при переводе всё в Int64 массив за пределы не выходит?

Comment: Чтобы исправить, надо понимать, где идёт обращение к массиву и устранить выход за границу. Как это делается в C++ можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1341757/176217), но у вас кода не видно в вопросе.

Comment: Я просто не совсем понимаю как вообще может быть выход за пределы массива, если я на 2-м скрине получаю длину синего массива (20 элементов), и делаю ресайз красного массива (тоже в 20 элементов). Почему он просит вообще что либо больше чем 20 я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

На первом скрине ошибка "попытка получения элемента массива с индексом 20, при длине массива 20". Индекс крайнего элемента массива длиной 20 элементов равен 19. Проверьте все условия в циклах и ветвлениях, куда-то закралось обращение за пределы массива.
Увидеть бы листинг который выбрасывает ошибку.

Comment: Возможно дело в цикле. Если установить параметр Size to fit, то он будет раздувать массив до бесконечности. Если подскажите как в UE4 получить листнинг то я вам его скину.